# Similarity-based binary representation of graph

Tags: graphs, randomness

I have given an undirected graph of which I want to associate every vertex with a (random) binary vector. I can chose the dimensionality of the vector but it has to be identical for every vertex. The main constraint is that the closer two vertices are in the graph, the lower the Hamming distance between the two associated binary vectors should be. The exact Hamming distance between two specific vertices may vary, as long as the average Hamming distance growths with the distance within the graph.

Do you have any pointers or ideas to a systematic solution to this problem? I was thinking about a breadth-first construction process, but was not sure whether this gives me the best solution for nodes which are reached over multiple paths.

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: Asked on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11183/how-can-i-embed-an-n-points-metric-space-to-a-hypercube-with-low-distortion.